# Surjectivity of a function using calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Consider $f:\{ x \in \mathbb R  | x=0    $  or $ sin(\dfrac{1}{x}) \geq 0 \} \subset \mathbb R  \longmapsto \mathbb R$; $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $f(x)=x^2sin(\dfrac{1}{x})$ if $x\neq 0 $ and $g:[0,\infty)\subset \mathbb R \longmapsto \mathbb R$; $g(y)=\sqrt y$

Show that $R(f)=D(y)$

Here's what i have:

$\subseteq )$ Since  $sin(\dfrac{1}{x}) \geq 0 $ and $x^{2} \geq0 \Rightarrow f(x) \geq 0$ and its trivial.

$\supseteq$ Let $y \in [0,\infty) $ we need to find $x \in \{ x \in \mathbb R | x=0    $  or $ sin(\dfrac{1}{x}) \geq 0 \}$ such that  $f(x)=y$. I want to use the Intermediate-value Theorem of Continuous Functions. It doesn't occurs to me other way to solve this. I already know that f is continuous because $\lim_{x \to 0} xsin(1/x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} x=0$ (thus $f$ is continuous in $0$, the rest of the continuity follows for product of continuous functions on $f$ domain). If $y=0$, we have and $x=0 \in D(f)$ such that $f(0)=0=y$. Suppose that $0<y$. To use the theorem, i need to find $f(b)>y$ for some $b \in D(f)$. The function will be continuous on $[0,b]$, that will imply that exists a $\xi \in (0,b)$ such that $f(\xi)=y$. I don't find the goddamn point. I tried archimedian property: $y<k<2\pi + k$. My other tools are Chain rule and derivative of the inverse funtion. This exercise appears on Sagan's book "Advanced Calculus" page 127.

Comment: What is $sen$ ? .............

Comment: sin but in spanish. I already edited it.

Comment: Not particularly relevant to the question, but the symbol $\Re$ (`\Re`) is typically reserved for "real part", as in the real part of a complex numbers. Similarly, $\Im$ (`\Im`) denotes "imaginary part". You can denote the set of real numbers by $\mathbb R$ (`\mathbb R`).

Answer (score 3):

You want to show that $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ is unbounded.

If you know Taylor series, this is essentially because $\sin h=h+O(h^3)$ as $h\to0$. Alternatively,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(1/x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h-\sin0}{h}=\cos0=1,$$
so $x^2\sin(1/x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't know that yet but by contradiction its true that i need to find that f is unbounded.

Comment: Does my alternative method work? All you need is that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$.

Comment: I don't know because i haven't seen the definition of "limit of a function when $x$ ---> $\infty$". Only in sequences. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want, just take $a_n=n\sin(1/n)$, then as before $a_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ so you conclude that $na_n=n^2\sin(1/n)\to\infty$.